# How can i use CVS version control in QT

Tags: qt, cvs

[image: My current software]

Hey I am trying to connect my Qt creator to my CVS. At the moment i am using it separated but i have seen version control options for it.

Now i have looked but no clear answer/or answer that worked has shown up.

Every one revers to the option Tools-->CVS, but this option in not in my list. The plugin is installed.

I am working on a Windows 10 computer and the information in the top shows my Qt and CVS versions.

My question is how can i use my CVS version control in QT?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sur the CVS plugin is actually loaded. Go to `Help > About Plugins...` and ensure the CSV plugin has a green check icon.

Then ensure the CVS plugin is configured properly. Go to `Tools > Options`, under "Version Control" you should have a CVS tab with multiple options.

If it still does not work, you might want to report a bug in: https://bugreports.qt.io/

Comment: The tab is there but still have no option off using it.

Comment: @vincentpoortvliet Have you set the path to the CVS exe file?